# How to get sum of two quantity columns based on different grouping conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

[image: Table1]
[image: Table2]

From the inner join of  table1 and table2, joined on delivery,  i want to get sum of qty_to_ship based on grouping plant, parts, and exp_ship_date and sum of qty_shipped based on grouping plant, parts, and book_date. the idea is to calculate quantities shipped based on book_date and quantities to be shipped based on exp_ship_date.

i tried use sub query but couldn't get correct answers

what i tried

```
DECLARE @REPORT AS NVARCHAR(50)='2019-06-19 00:00:00.000'
SELECT
    PLANT,
    PARTS,
    YEAR(P_DATE) AS P_DATE,MONTH(P_DATE) AS P_DATE,DAY(P_DATE) AS P_DATE,
    ES_DATE AS ES_DATE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (P_DATE<@REPORT AND P_DATE > DATEADD(DAY,-7,@REPORT)) THEN QTY_PICKED ELSE 0 END) AS SHIPPED,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ES_DATE>@REPORT AND ES_DATE < DATEADD(DAY,7,@REPORT) THEN QTY_MII ELSE 0 END) -SUM(CASE WHEN ES_DATE>@REPORT AND ES_DATE < DATEADD(DAY,7,@REPORT) THEN QTY_PICKED ELSE 0 END)  AS TO_SHIP
      FROM TABLE1 T1
      INNER JOIN
      TABLE2 T2 
      ON
      T1.DELIVERY = T2.DELIVERY

WHERE PLANT = 'XXX'
GROUP BY
    GROUPING SETS (
        (PLANT, PARTS,YEAR(P_DATE),MONTH(P_DATE),DAY(P_DATE)),
        (PLANT, PARTS,ES_DATE)
    )
ORDER BY
PLANT,
PARTS
```

Comment: please show what you have tried and also the expected result

Comment: added below "what i tried "

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OVER` clause to calculated aggregations based on different groupings for each row:

```
SELECT *
     ,SUM(qty_to_ship) OVER (PARTITION BY plant, parts, exp_ship_date)
     ,SUM(qty_shipped) OVER (PARTITION BY plant, parts, book_date)
FROM table1 A
INNER JOIN table2 B
    ON A.[Delivery] = B.[Delivery];
```

then leave the columns you need and use `DISTINCT` to remove the duplicate rows. For example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.develiery
               ,A.plant
               ,A.parts
               ,SUM(qty_to_ship) OVER (PARTITION BY plant, parts, exp_ship_date)
               ,SUM(qty_shipped) OVER (PARTITION BY plant, parts, book_date)
FROM table1 A
INNER JOIN table2 B
    ON A.[Delivery] = B.[Delivery];
```

Comment: i get error PLANT is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: DECLARE @REPORT AS NVARCHAR(50)='2019-06-19 00:00:00.000'
SELECT *,
  
  SUM(CASE WHEN (P_DATE<@REPORT AND P_DATE > DATEADD(DAY,-7,@REPORT)) THEN QTY_PICKED ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY PLANT,PARTS,P_DATE)AS SHIPPED,
  SUM(CASE WHEN E_DATE>@REPORT AND E_DATE < DATEADD(DAY,7,@REPORT) THEN QTY_MII ELSE 0 END) -SUM(CASE WHEN E_DATE>@REPORT AND E_DATE < DATEADD(DAY,7,@REPORT) THEN QTY_PICKED ELSE 0 END) AS TO_SHIP
 FROM TABLE1 T1
   INNER JOIN
      TABLE2 T2 
      ON
      T1.DELIVERY = T2.DELIVERY

WHERE PLANT = 'XXX'

Comment: You need to apply `OVER` clause for each aggregate function.